# How do I extract value of a JSON key using bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, json

I'm using bash shell.  I would like to include something in my shell script that can extract the value of a certain key in a JSON string ...

```
davea$ json='{"id": "abc", "name": "dave"}'
```

I tried "grep", which failed

```
davea$ grep -Po '"id":.*?[^\\]",' $json
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Then I found a solution involving Python, but this also failed ...

```
localhost:tmp davea$ echo $json | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["id"]'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["id"]
```

How can I extract the value for the "id" key without installing anything extra on my system?

Comment: Install `jq` or `json` or don't work with JSON data.

Comment: Your python code works well for python2.x, and should work for python3 if you put brackets around the `print` argument.

Comment: @pLumo -- that was the issue, I had Python 3 installed but the code I was using was Python 2.

Comment: Your title says you want to use the `bash` shell, but your examples uses `grep` and `python`. Would it be ok to update the title?

Answer (score 3):

Your python code works well.
Be aware that you might need brackets around the argument to `print` if you use `python3`.

```
echo "$json" | python2 -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["id"]'

echo "$json" | python3 -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print(obj["id"])'
```

Alternatively, use `jq`:

```
echo "$json" | jq -r .id
```

Output for all solutions above:

```
abc
```